# Generating windows exe

Tags: windows, visual-c++, executable, embedded-resource, portable-executable

The requirement is to build a program that generates a windows exe which will display some ***embedded*** web pages. The exe has to run on most windows versions without need of libraries so I guess it has to be MFC app statically linked.

This task is not trivial for me, I am not sure how to implement the system. My experience is mostly in C# and Java. My thoughts so far is to create the MFC program that loads the webpages from embedded resource file, then the generator program would change the resource to desired web pages at runtime and save the exe. Please advise if this is a sensible approach or some other way to solve the problem. Any advices, tools, sample codes or similar open source program links/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The software has to generate windows executables for the user. Program 1 generates program 2 which has the embedded web pages. I have to build the Program 1 that takes web pages from user as input and outputs an executable program 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your background I'd suggest a Delphi app using the TWebBrowser component. Delphi's GUI building tools are more akin to what you are used to than MFC. You could likely get it built in a matter of hours.

Regarding the resources I'd just handle that with a build script that linked different resources for different versions. If you want to avoid rebuilding for each version there are many tools for replacing resources in an existing executable.

I somewhat misunderstood your requirements. You want to update the EXE's resources programmatically which can be achieved using the UpdateResource() Windows API function.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, the executable has to be generated by the generator program at runtime, not compiled. The user opens the generator program picks some web pages they want to embed and the generator program builds the (single file) executable with embedded web pages for viewing. Not so simple :/

Comment: no that's trivial with the UpdateResource windows api function.

Comment: Thank you very much, that function is exactly what I was looking for! Would never guess windows api has such function.